# Facebook OpenID authentication not functioning

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, facebook, authentication

I have been attempting to change my OpenID to facebook, but have not been successful. The first time I attempted it, it brought up facebook and asked for permissions. I added the permissions for stack exchange in facebook. Now when I choose "log in with facebook" from the openid options under "change openid" in my profile, the link takes me back to my profile page and changes nothing. When I choose another openid, it fills in the openid link in the input box below and goes to the authentication page for permissions for that website and upon acceptance, it changes the openid in my superuser profile.

Is anyone else experiencing issues with adding facebook at this time?

Comment: I just successfully added Facebook as an open id on my SU account.  Are you still having an issue?

Comment: I still can't. I am trying from a different computer this time. I had been trying with Firefox. I retested with IE and still got the same results. Every time I click to log in with Facebook, it goes back to my profile page and nothing changes. Same result on every SE site that I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this will go out with the next build (exact timing dependent on when the database move is completed).

There was a rather subtle bug around adding new identifiers if both identifiers were known to verify e-mail addresses (for instance, Google and Facebook are both trusted; MyOpenId is not).