# Why would one need multiple OpenIDs?

Tags: support, openid

In the user page there is **add openid** link? Why would one need multiple OpenIDs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case one of your OpenID provides suddenly disappears, it saves you a lot of hassle from having to email Stack Exchange and proving your identity. Instead, you simply login with the other OpenID and everything continues to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think this says everything:

[MyOpenID account mysteriously vanished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/lost-my-openid-account)

Occasionally, your OpenID provider (external to Stack Exchange) does something crazy.

Comment: Or, occasionally your favorite website [might break something subtle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82479/facebook-openid-authentication-not-functioning/82811#82811) ;-)