# Can't log in using myOpenID

Tags: discussion, login

I get the following error when I try to log in through my myOpenID account:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

Comment: On this specific site?

Comment: I do not use my open id on any other sites.

Comment: had this yesterday. after 2 hours later i had access and have to reset my password.

Comment: Alright, which open id provider do you use?

Comment: yesterday i thaught it had to do with the amazon cloud service outage. now i am afraid they're hacked... :-(

Comment: @Ancide: I use myopen id.

Comment: @Snoopy: I'm facing this problem from yesterday.

Comment: Take a look [Lost my OpenID account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/lost-my-openid-account)

Comment: I guess your MyOpenID account is also deleted. (if so this should be closed as duplicate).