# Not able to update profile (Email is already registered)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-page

I recently took the plunge and registered for a couple of more Stack Exchange 2.0 sites and started updating my profiles.  Upon saving, I was greeted with this message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> Email is already registered

The thing is, I haven't even touched my email.  Logging off, updating and saving doesn't seem to fix it.  This wasn't a problem when I updated my profiles on other sites (Super User and here) some months ago.  Checking again, I'm not able to update my profile on any site any more (not even Stack Overflow).  I noticed that [previous problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22email%20is%20already%20registered%22) are either really old or was about careers.

Did a recent update break it?

Possibly related to this recent post: [MyOpenID account mysteriously vanished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished).  (I'm using a Google account.)

I've tried this on Firefox 3.6, Firefox  4.0 and Internet Explorer 9.0 and clearing the cache, nothing.

Comment: Repro'd on mine too here.

Comment: May be they're locking updates to profiles because of [recent myopenid issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished)

Comment: I was just coming to ask the same thing.

Comment: @YOU: Ah good catch.

Comment: Seems to work now.

Comment: @Oliver: Yep, there it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bug, a fix will be deployed shortly.

Part of the dapper migration was changing all validations so they are less side effecty, we had a bunch of validations in the user model that were run when a property was set on the user. This caused havoc when loading records from the db.

Comment: That was a fast fix.  :)

Comment: @Jeff ... the wheel of blame was spinning fast, I needed to stop it :)

Comment: bad code offsets?

Comment: Hello, I still see this with my account.  I'm not sure if I inadvertently created two accounts which are both tied to the same email address.  This is only affecting my Stackoverflow account, the meta Stackoverflow account is okay.  Let me know if there's any additional information I could provide.

Comment: @Bryan ... sounds like you need to merge 2 accounts

Comment: Same problem here. I only have one account, although I previously had myself removed from one stackexchange site.