# Careers not able to update personal details?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I am not able to update personal details in Careers, it is showing some irrelevant error message!

**What I tried:**
I tried to update my mailing address.
With all other details the same, I got this error.
Due to this, I am not able to update details.

Maybe [Not able to update profile (Email is already registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/not-able-to-update-profile-email-is-already-registered) is referring to the same issue.
When this will be **fixed**?

[image]

Comment: We've merged what appeared to be duplicate accounts. Would you try it again?

Comment: @MattSherman Now it's working fine, Could you please explain what is the problem and how you resolved it, as an answer!