# Cannot update my profile - email in use?

Tags: support, status-completed, email

I'm having the same problem from [this thread.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/not-able-to-update-profile-email-is-already-registered)

Even though it is said the issue was addressed, whenever I try to update my profile, it says my email is already registered. I had an OpenID associated with another account, but I deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your old and new accounts have now been merged, enjoy!

Comment: Forgot to say thanks! Thanks!