# Can't edit my profile

Tags: support, profile-page

Whenever I try to edit something on my profile the changes are denied and this message shows:

Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

I'm trying to edit my profile so I'm already logged in. I don't know how to fix it to be able to update my profile information correctly.

Comment: Which site are you trying to made the edit on?

Comment: Looks like you have an old account using the same email address, it has to be merged into your existing account, as can be seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158260/cannot-update-my-profile-email-in-use). @Oded can you find and merge those account like Nick did in there?

Comment: By the way, the message means "log in using the other account using this email address" but agree it's not very clear.

Comment: I can see a merge happened a couple of days ago. Try logging out, clearing all cookies and logging back in.

Comment: It's working now, I beleive it was just a matter of giving it some time to complete the merge. Thanks a lot for the comments.