# Error while updating Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

When I try to update my profile, I get this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in
>   above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this
>   account.

Earlier I had merged another Stack Overflow account with this one. But, I don't have any issues in accessing the account. The only thing is that I cannot update my profile.

Comment: See [this comment by Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222935/cant-edit-my-profile#comment725894_222935). Does it work in your case as well?

Comment: I did the merge about 3 months ago.

Comment: You do have another account that uses the same email address. I can't/won't post the credential email used on it publicly, but... think of another Gmail address you may have used to log in in the past. If you still can't think of one, drop us a line using the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page and explain the situation/reference this post.