# Oops! There was a problem updating your profile

Tags: support, profile-page, email

I think I accidently created two accounts and now I cannot change my username:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: •This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

I did the recovery process but that did not help! I know that this question was asked multiple times but I cannot find a solution for me. Similar topics for example:
[Cannot update my profile - email in use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158260/cannot-update-my-profile-email-in-use)
[Not able to update profile (Email is already registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/not-able-to-update-profile-email-is-already-registered)

How to merge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found and merged your profiles. You should be all set.

Let us know if you need anything else. :)

If anyone else is experiencing the same issue, [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and we'll fix it for you.

Comment: I'm having same issue. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Victorifeanyi Done, you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks so much @AdamLear