# Unable to update profile at Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I try to update my account at Stack Overflow, but see this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

Do I have the same problem as [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228924/oops-there-was-a-problem-updating-your-profile)? Or something else is going on?

Comment: Did you had accounts merged? If yes, then the other question applies.

Comment: @rene I don't know, I guess, I didn't. I guess, mods should know :)

Comment: You can also try the contact us link at the bottom of the page to mail the team directly. it needs a dev to resolve I guess.